# Adding data to context at specific location

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is a Console application, im just experimenting and learning.
The problem is i dont understand how to add data at specific locations to the database.

Here are my models:

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual int entityId { get; set; }
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
    public virtual int lvl { get; set; }
    public virtual double hp { get; set; }
    public virtual int maxhp { get; set; }

    public virtual Inventory inventory { get; set; }
    public virtual Equipment equipment { get; set; }

    public virtual Skill skills { get; set; }
}

public class Inventory
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int invId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Item> items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public virtual int itemId { get; set; }
    public virtual string itemName { get; set; }
    public virtual string type {get;set;}
}

public class Skill
{
    public virtual int skillId { get; set; }
    public virtual string skillName { get; set; }
    public virtual string type { get; set; }
}

public class Equipment
{
    public virtual int equipmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item helmet { get; set; }
    public virtual Item body { get; set; }
    public virtual Item legs { get; set; }
    public virtual Item weapon { get; set; }

}
```

I want to add new items to the Items table that is in many to one relation with Inventories.
I want to add data to a specific inventory.
My problem is that if i do this

```
Inventory inv = db.Entities.Where(e => e.entityId == eId).FirstOrDefault<Entity>().inventory;
                inv.items.Add(item);
                //db.Items.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

then the item wont get added at all

if i do this

```
    Inventory inv = db.Entities.Where(e => e.entityId == eId).FirstOrDefault<Entity>().inventory;
                //inv.items.Add(item);
                db.Items.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

then the item wont get assigned to proper inventory and Inventory_InvId will be NULL

but if i do this

```
        Inventory inv = db.Entities.Where(e => e.entityId == eId).FirstOrDefault<Entity>().inventory;
                inv.items.Add(item);
                db.Items.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Then item will be added properly.
Can anyone explain why it behaves like this?
Also could anyone show me a proper way of adding items at specific places?

Comment: Case 1 should work. What SQL is being [logged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx)?

Comment: Im sorry, i have found my error. I should add

inv.items = new List<Item>();

before

 inv.items.Add(item);

Also now i can delete db.Items.Add(item);

And now it works.